# Custom Liking Function

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have a comics site where I'd like to build my own like and dislike function.

I was thinking of just using Facebook's, but here are the reasons why I'd like my own:

1. Want to collect both likes and dislikes. Facebook like button cannot do this.
2. Want to create a custom graphic for the likes and dislikes
3. Want to collect likes and dislikes associated by comic id and use it to sort by popularity

The function works by a user clicking the like button, a script will log that IP into the database... if an entry exists where that IP has already liked a certain imd id, it won't increment the like count associated with that img id.

While testing the function, I realized it would be challenging from a scalability perspective **for 2 reasons:**

1. The burden on the database will be n unique IPs * x comics. For example, 3,000 fans have the potential to like 60 comics, which is 180,000 entries. Plus, that's a lot of queries going back and forth to the server... not to mention each time someone may unlike and relike an image. I get hosting through GoDaddy, so size on the server may be an issue.
2. Manageability. I'm not sure how challenging it'd be to clean up an error or bug if there are so many entries.

So, my questions are:

1) Would it make sense to build my own?

2) Are there pre-built liking/disliking functions that I can just implement?

3) What are the challenges in scaling?

Comment: The question is a bit to broad. Suggest replacing "any thoughts?" with a set of concrete questions (indicating that you have done your research on the topic as well).

Comment: 180000 entries in a properly indexed database is *nothing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Its a really simple model... a table of comics key'd by id, a table of likes with a unique composite key of comic ID and ip address

2) Even if there is something pre built for the frontend javascript... depending on your knowledge it would be pretty easy to implement

3) none really - as deceze said in a comment, 180,000 entries in a simple table like this properly indexed would be a walk in the park for any db server..

It's a bit of a high level answer but with fairly basic knowledge of PHP you should be able to implement it!

Comment: I've already built the function... and it works... it's just that during testing I Was thinking about continuing on or not due to those questions above

Comment: ok.. I would not worry about scaling issues based on what you have said. Regarding your 1st reason - its really not that many queries - its potentially checking to see if a like exists already / if it can insert a like/dislike.. the 2nd reason - its not too complicated such that you couldnt replicate any error or bug using only a small number of comics/test users.. It's right to question scalability however in this case I don't believe you need to worry further